# Compare string vs modified strings & partial strings

Tags: python

I have a list of links, and I want to see if they're listed in my disavow file.

My disavow file contains both URLs (e.g. `http://getpaydayloan.org/blog/blog-how-to-apply-for-online-payday-loans-san`) as well as whole domains, listed as `domain:getpaydayloan.org`.

The new URLs file holds URLs only, e.g. `http://getpaydayloan.org/blog/blog-how-to-apply-for-online-payday-loans-san`

I want to see if the new URLs are already in the disavow file. I am currently generating a diff using `diff = set(url_set)-set(disavow_urls)`, but I also need to check to see if they are in the disavow file using the `domain:url.com` format.

How would I do something like that?

In case it helps, here is the whole script: https://github.com/growth-austen/disavow_automator

Comment: `http://getpaydayloan.org/blog/blog-how-to-apply-for-online-payday-loans-san` is not a domain...

Comment: You may want to look into https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html

Comment: Whoops, sorry, meant URLs. Thanks.

Comment: There are efficient ways to do this, but there's only a need if there's a lot of data. How many lines are you expecting in the two file? A simple nested loop over both files may be enough.

Comment: @AlexHall Nexted loops are fine (I think). Maybe a few thousand in the disavow, ~50 in the URLs

Comment: Yep, that'll be fine. As long as the product is under a million you don't need to start to worry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a function to check if the url contains any of the disavowed domains.

```
def inDisavow(url, disavowDomainList):
    for domain in disavowDomainList:
        if domain in url:
            return true
    return false
```

Comment: These work in the case we're comparing `http://someurl.com/123` in the URLs to `http://someurl.com/123` in the disavow, but not if we're comparing `http://someurl.com/123` to `domain:someurl.com`.

I think the part that was tripping me up was being able to parse the domain; if I can strip the `http://` and the `/123` off, keep the `someurl.com`, and compare that against `domain:someurl.com`. So Wayne should have given me enough to start.

Thanks!

Comment: If your disavow strings are always domain:url.com, you could also strip off the 'domain:' part by modifying the if statement to "if domain[7:] in url:"

Answer (score 1):

Some alternative definitions to David's function for fun:

`return any(domain in url for domain in disavowDomainList)
 return any(map(url.__contains__, disavowDomainList))`

(replace `map` with `itertools.imap` in Python 2 for memory efficiency)